# D tool ddemangle.d doesn't change output from DMD+GNU ld linking Errors

Tags: d, ld, dmd, linker-errors, demangler

I'm trying to demangle my linking errors such as

```
dmd -debug -gc -unittest -D -Dd/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/ -w  ~/Work/cognia/t_geometry.d -of/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/t_geometry
/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/t_geometry.o:(.data+0x6d8): undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg12__ModuleInfoZ'
/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/t_geometry.o: In function `_D4gl3n6linalg16__T6VectorTfVi4Z6Vector19__unittestL103_7189FNaNbNfZv':
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:104: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg15__unittest_failFiZv'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:105: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg15__unittest_failFiZv'
```

by using `ddemangle.d` from dtools repo on github as

```
same_command_as_above | ddemangle
```

but I get the same output using both DMD 2.063.2 and git master.

Is ddemangle.d not uptodate?

**Update**: Ok. Thanks!

```
same_command_as_above 2>&1 | ddemangle
```

demangles the majority of the messages but not all of them. I wonder why. Here's some lines

```
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1814: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi2Vi2Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi2Vi2Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1815: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
```

Clues anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are filtering the output stream that the program is emitting. Errors are commonly written to the standard error stream, but the line above only filters standard output stream.

Try changing your command to:

```
same_command_as_above 2>&1 | ddemangle
```

`2>&1` will redirect stderr to stdout, allowing `ddemangle` to filter both stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thanks!

```
same_command_as_above 2>&1 | ddemangle
```

demangles the majority of the messages but not all of them. I wonder why. Here's some lines

```
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1814: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi2Vi2Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi2Vi2Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1815: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1817: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1818: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi4Vi4Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi4Vi4Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1820: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi4Vi4Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi4Vi4Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1821: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi4Vi4Z6Matrix6__initZ'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:1823: undefined reference to `void gl3n.linalg.__unittest_fail(int)'
/home/per/Work/cognia/gl3n/linalg.d:695: undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg19__T6MatrixTfVi4Vi4Z6Matrix6__initZ'
```

Clues anyone?

Comment: The `__initZ` symbols contain the default value for a type (which is used to initialize new values). In the language, this corresponds to the implicit `.init` property of all types. These are not currently demangled - see [bug 10189](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=10189).

Comment: BTW, in the future you should post amendments to your question by editing your question, and leaving a comment on the answer you're following up to.